How to optimize the following structure as a vectorized operation
My end goal is to get c_indices as described here. However, I'm unable to find any good optimization to increase the speed. Is it even possible to perform some kind of vectorization to reduce the time complexity?
_c = np.random.randint(0,1000, (10000))

c_starts = np.concatenate([[0], np.cumsum(_c[:-1])])
c_indices =  np.concatenate([np.tile(np.arange(start, start + size), _c[i])
                              for i, (start, size) in enumerate(zip(c_starts, _c))])

for example for a given _c = [3, 4, 2], I would expect the following output
>>> _c
[3, 4, 2]
>>> c_starts
array([0, 3, 7])
>>> c_indices
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 3, 4,
       5, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 8])

#based on _c = [3, 4, 2]
#[0, 1, 2] -> repeated 3 times 
#[3, 4, 5, 6] -> repeated 4 times 
#[7, 8] -> repeated 2 times 





np.tile(np.arange(start, start + size), size)? Since you are repeating an array of length size size times, I don't see how can avoid iterating like this.

Can c_indices be int32? It would be twice as fast. Also, your current implementation uses about 50GB of memory. Do you have enough physical memory?

Sorry, I had a feeling it cannot be optimitzed, but wanted to see if there was a workaround!!!

I have numba solution that takes about 60% of the original time (at least on my machine). It also should significantly lower memory consumption.
import numpy as np
import numba

@numba.njit("int32[:](int32[:], int32[:])")
def simple_tiling_numba(starts, sizes):
    tiled_starts = np.zeros(len(sizes) + 1, dtype=np.int64)
    tiled_starts[1:] = np.cumsum(sizes ** 2)

    result = np.full(tiled_starts[-1], 0, dtype=np.int32)
    for idx in range(len(starts)):
        start = starts[idx]
        size = sizes[idx]
        an_array = np.arange(start, start+size)
        if size > 0:
            for idx2 in range(tiled_starts[idx], tiled_starts[idx+1], size):
                result[idx2:idx2+size] = an_array
    return result


def main():
    _c = np.random.randint(0, 1000, (10000))

    c_starts = np.concatenate([[0], np.cumsum(_c[:-1])])
    c_indices = np.concatenate([np.tile(np.arange(start, start + size), _c[i])
                                for i, (start, size) in enumerate(zip(c_starts, _c))])
    c_indices2 = simple_tiling_numba(c_starts, sizes=_c)
    assert (np.all(c_indices == c_indices2))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Tried parallelizing and it improves performance compared to non-parallel numba but only slightly (10-20%) at the cost of 2x time CPU consumption:
@numba.njit("int32[:](int32[:], int32[:])", parallel=True)
def simple_tiling_numba_parallel(starts, sizes):
    tiled_starts = np.zeros(len(sizes) + 1, dtype=np.int64)
    tiled_starts[1:] = np.cumsum(sizes ** 2)

    result = np.full(tiled_starts[-1], 0, dtype=np.int32)
    for idx in numba.prange(len(starts)):
        start = starts[idx]
        size = sizes[idx]
        an_array = np.arange(start, start+size)
        if size > 0:
            for idx2 in range(tiled_starts[idx], tiled_starts[idx+1], size):
                result[idx2:idx2+size] = an_array
    return result


Yup, I just went with cuda, which reduced the time from seconds to milliseconds. There is no efficient  way with broadcasting.

What you can do is :

Avoiding Concatenation: By directly assigning values to pre-allocated arrays, you avoid the overhead of repeatedly concatenating arrays, which can be slow.

Efficient Memory Usage: Pre-allocating the c_indices array and then filling it avoids the inefficiency of repeated array creation and copying.


For that :

Construct c_indices:

Use np.empty to allocate memory for c_indices.
The loop fills c_indices by broadcasting the range of indices for each segment into the appropriate positions.



# Create the indices array
# The length of c_indices should be the sum of _c
num_elements = np.sum(_c)
c_indices = np.empty(num_elements, dtype=int)

# Fill the c_indices array using broadcasting
current_start = 0
for i, size in enumerate(_c):
    end = current_start + size
    c_indices[current_start:end] = np.arange(c_starts[i], c_starts[i] + size)
    current_start = end

